# Priority precedence of operations in the JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I would like to improve my app in JavaScript by implementing a new modern features : the priority precedence of the operations. What I meant by that is as follows. The app, the calculator will be able to show the parentheses buttons : ( and ) so that it should be able to operate with them.
For example Input = (2+3) * (20-10)  should logically output 50.
How can I handle the parentheses as the priority precedence in my app please?

My operate function

```js
export default function operate(numberOne, numberTwo, operation) {
  const one = Big(numberOne);
  const two = Big(numberTwo);
  if (operation === '+') {
    return one.plus(two).toString();
  }
  if (operation === '-') {
    return one.minus(two).toString();
  }
  if (operation === 'x') {
    return one.times(two).toString();
  }
  ......
  }
```

My calculate operation look like the following:

```
import operate from './operate';

function isNumber(item) {
  return !!item.match(/[0-9]+/);
}

/**
 * Given a button name and a calculator data object, return an updated
 * calculator data object.
 *
 * Calculator data object contains:
 *   total:s      the running total
 *   next:String       the next number to be operated on with the total
 *   operation:String  +, -, etc.
 */
export default function calculate(obj, buttonName) {
  if (buttonName === 'AC') {
    return {
      total: null,
      next: null,
      operation: null,
    };
  }

  if (isNumber(buttonName)) {
    if (buttonName === '0' && obj.next === '0') {
      return {};
    }
    // If there is an operation, update next
    if (obj.operation) {
      if (obj.next) {
        return { ...obj, next: obj.next + buttonName };
      }
      return { ...obj, next: buttonName };
    }
    // If there is no operation, update next and clear the value
    if (obj.next) {
      return {
        next: obj.next + buttonName,
        total: null,
      };
    }
    return {
      next: buttonName,
      total: null,
    };
  }

  if (buttonName === '.') {
    if (obj.next) {
      if (obj.next.includes('.')) {
        return { ...obj };
      }
      return { ...obj, next: `${obj.next}.` };
    }
    if (obj.operation) {
      return { next: '0.' };
    }
    if (obj.total) {
      if (obj.total.includes('.')) {
        return {};
      }
      return { total: `${obj.total}.` };
    }
    return { total: '0.' };
  }

  if (buttonName === '=') {
    if (obj.next && obj.operation) {
      return {
        total: operate(obj.total, obj.next, obj.operation),
        next: null,
        operation: null,
      };
    }
    // '=' with no operation, nothing to do
    return {};
  }

  if (buttonName === '+/-') {
    if (obj.next) {
      return { ...obj, next: (-1 * parseFloat(obj.next)).toString() };
    }
    if (obj.total) {
      return { ...obj, total: (-1 * parseFloat(obj.total)).toString() };
    }
    return {};
  }

  // Button must be an operation

  // When the user presses an operation button without having entered
  // a number first, do nothing.
  if (!obj.next && !obj.total) {
    return {};
  }

  // User pressed an operation after pressing '='

  if (!obj.next && obj.total && !obj.operation) {
    return { ...obj, operation: buttonName };
  }

  // User pressed an operation button and there is an existing operation
  if (obj.operation) {
    if (obj.total && !obj.next) {
      return { ...obj, operation: buttonName };
    }

    return {
      total: operate(obj.total, obj.next, obj.operation),
      next: null,
      operation: buttonName,
    };
  }

  // no operation yet, but the user typed one

  // The user hasn't typed a number yet, just save the operation
  if (!obj.next) {
    return { operation: buttonName };
  }

  // save the operation and shift 'next' into 'total'
  return {
    total: obj.next,
    next: null,
    operation: buttonName,
  };
}
```

This calculate is used in the calculator component by the handleEvent function

```
const handleEvent = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, ...calculate(state, e.target.name) });
  };
```

And the UI use the handleEvent to show the button:

```
 <button type="button" className="grayButton" name="(" onClick={handleEvent}>(</button>
 <button type="button" className="grayButton" name=")" onClick={handleEvent}>)</button>
```

Comment: Don't operate on buttons. Write a parser for mathematical expressions.